# ActionBar CustomView visibility in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock action bar and i have 4 fragments. I use action bar custom view in 4th fragment.

```
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this.thisContext).inflate(R.layout.about_custom_view, null); // layout which contains your button.
    actionbar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);

    actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    Button abouButton = (Button)customNav.findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
```

Now problem is that custom view is appearing in it 3rd fragment as well although is set

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
```

Please give me any sloution.
Thanks

Comment: In 4th fragment destroyView method set this : actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

Comment: i wanted to add custom view in 4th tab.

Comment: Check your java code you will get...